# Getting last child in SimpleXMLElement Object with PHP

Tags: php, xml

again I think I'm missing something really basic here, but I really can't figure it out.

I'm parsing an xml file formatted as excel, using SimpleXML in PHP.

My xml file looks like the following:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( 

[DocumentProperties] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
    [Author] => Surname Name 
    [LastAuthor] => Name Surname 
    [Created] => 2016-08-01T10:15:25Z 
    [Version] => 14.00 ) 

[OfficeDocumentSettings] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [AllowPNG] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) ) 

[ExcelWorkbook] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [WindowHeight] => 9375 [WindowWidth] => 9705 [WindowTopX] => 270 [WindowTopY] => 615 [ProtectStructure] => False [ProtectWindows] => False ) 

[Styles] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [Style] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [Alignment] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [Font] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) ) ) 

[Worksheet] => Array ( 

[0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
    [Table] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
            [Column] => Array (
                [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) 
                [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) 
                [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) )

            [Row] => Array ( 
                [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
                    [Cell] => Array ( 
                        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [Data] => Model ) 
                        [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [Data] => Qty ) 
                        [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [Data] => Description ) 
                        [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [Data] => Tags ) ) ) 

                [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
                    [Cell] => Array ( 
                        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [Data] => model_name ) 
                        [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [Data] => 1 ) 
                        [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [Data] => This is my item ) ) ) 

[....code repeats with other rows/worksheets....]
```

Now, if I want to display the Author name, I can simply do something like:
    echo $xml->DocumentProperties->LastAuthor;
and I will get the expected result. How do I get to display the values in the various rows/cells (keeping in mind that the xml files will have a very diverse number of rows and rows are not always completely filled)?

I've tried something like the following:

```
echo $xml->Worksheet[0]->Table->Row[0]->Cell[0];
```

But doing so doesn't return any value. I would also like to be able to cycle through all the rows so that I can display them as an HTML table.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Comment: Try `echo $xml->Worksheet[0]->Table->Row[0]->Cell[0]->Data;`

Comment: And `foreach($xml->Worksheet as $Worksheet){ foreach($Worksheet->Table->Row as $Row){ foreach($Row->Cell as $Cell){ print $Cell->Data; }}} `

Comment: Maybe you have to do `print (string)$Cell->Data;`

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions the method you described works perfectly thanks. Now I have a final question, to improve the parsing result: how can I skip some rows in the loop? Let's say that I always want to skip row[0] since I want to replace the headers with my own, can I use a $counter and start from row[1]?